# Could you help me understand red black trees insertion algorithm?

Tags: data-structures

I'm diving deeper into data structures and trying to understand in all details Red-Black trees. It doesn't seem to way hard, I checked the Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). The problem that I can't understand the sentence:

`G is known to be black, since its former child P could not have been red without violating property 4.`

from the insertion procedure Case 4, step 2. It's clear G is black but it's unclear why P can't be red while it's red. It was red without violating property 4. And I don't see a connection between G and P in this sentence.

There are can be two cases - either I don't understand something or there is an error on Wikipedia and it should be fixed.

Could you help me clarify this moment? Thank you in advance!

Comment: There are strict rules inside RBT and one of them is "4. If a node is red, then both its children are black." So, if one child is red then its parent is black. Maybe the sentence is a little bit confusing, but it means "We know that G is black, because in another case it is impossible for P to be red."

Comment: Could you clarify why "if one child is red then its parent is black"? From property 4 it's clear on the way from parent to children, red nodes have black children but there is no word about black paren, it can have red/black children in any combination.